# `openssl s_server` giving less information than it used to

Tags: openssl

on my old GNU/Linux installation (Debian Stretch), I used to start a dummy openssl server `openssl s_server` and get the SSL session parameters printed on stdout.

The output was the following, and it was fine:

```
user@machine:~$ openssl s_server -port 7777 -cert zertifikat-with-pass.pem
Enter pass phrase for zertifikat-with-pass.pem:
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT
-----BEGIN SSL SESSION PARAMETERS-----
MGwCAQECAgMDBALAMxxxxDAjDcg5OEgtjf/KPjKlg4uoVzKJ8tXA1mWpJa8iMuxU
JTrQHFYKCvkAY5KodwontqihBgIEWxka06IEAgIcIKQGBAQBAAAAphAEDjE5Mi4x
NjguNDIuMTQ1rQMCAQE= (mangled for confidentiality)
-----END SSL SESSION PARAMETERS-----
Shared ciphers:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA1
Shared Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA1
Supported Elliptic Curve Point Formats: uncompressed:ansiX962_compressed_prime:ansiX962_compressed_char2
Supported Elliptic Curves: brainpoolP384r1:P-384:brainpoolP256r1:P-256
Shared Elliptic curves: P-384:P-256
CIPHER is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
CETP<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Event xmlns="http://domain.tld/v13.4"><Topic>DONE</Topic><Type>Operation</Type><Severity>Info</Severity><SubscriptionID>977ef239-459c-41ba-87e7-e5811aef9637</SubscriptionID><Message/></Event>DONE
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
ACCEPT
```

On my new machine (Xubuntu 18.04), `openssl s_server` is giving me far less output. Amongst other, the SSL session parameters are missing:

```
user@machine:~$ openssl s_server -port 7777 -cert umgewandelt 
Enter pass phrase for umgewandelt:
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT

CETP<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Event xmlns="http://domain.tld/13.4"><Topic>DONE</Topic><Type>Operation</Type><Severity>Info</Severity><SubscriptionID>2dea3d71-4902-4775-9684-ad9dffe193c0</SubscriptionID><Message/></Event>DONE
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
ACCEPT
```

## Question

How can I have `openssl s_server` print the SSL session parameters as it used to?

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason during writing the question above. I thought I'll post what I found out as it may help others.

When you get presented the following prompt:

```
user@machine:~$ openssl s_server -port 7777 -cert zertifikat-with-pass.pem
Enter pass phrase for zertifikat-with-pass.pem:
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT
```

it is important NOT to press a key, as only then you get presented the SSL session parameters when a client connects.

If you press a key (enter in my case), the following output is missing: (SSL session parameters are mangled for confidentiality)

```
-----BEGIN SSL SESSION PARAMETERS-----
MGwCAQECAgMDBALAMxxxxDAjDcg5OEgtjf/KPjKlg4uoVzKJ8tXA1mWpJa8iMuxU
JTrQHFYKCvkAY5KodwontqihBgIEWxka06IEAgIcIKQGBAQBAAAAphAEDjE5Mi4x
NjguNDIuMTQ1rQMCAQE=
-----END SSL SESSION PARAMETERS-----
Shared ciphers:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA1
Shared Signature Algorithms: RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1:ECDSA+SHA1
Supported Elliptic Curve Point Formats: uncompressed:ansiX962_compressed_prime:ansiX962_compressed_char2
Supported Elliptic Curves: brainpoolP384r1:P-384:brainpoolP256r1:P-256
Shared Elliptic curves: P-384:P-256
CIPHER is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
```